# Fixing timeout issue with a new connection

Tags: c#, ftp

This is my piece of code:

```
string my_dir = "";
try
{
    my_dir = ftp.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/test";
    //It sometimes crashes here. I get timeout error.
}
catch
{
    ftp.Close();
    ftp.Open();
    my_dir = ftp.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/test";
}
```

ftp is instance of the FtpConnection class: http://ftplib.codeplex.com/discussions?searchText=&size=10&page=1

This error happens on very large files. I'll have to wait about 2 hours to get it again. That's why I'm asking here. Does the code in the catch block have sense? Will it fix the timeout issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much you can do if the library doesn't expose a Timeout property. FtpConnection is a very thin wrapper over WinINET so your only option is to could write some P/Invoke code to alter WinINET's timeout.

Is there a reason you use this class?  .NET already has the [FtpWebRequest/FtpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229718.aspx) classes. You can alter the timeout of an operation using the [FtpWebRequest.Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.timeout.aspx) property or disable the timeout by passing the [Infinite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timeout.infinite.aspx) value (-1)